# Can I visit the UK and Ukraine on the same visa?

Tags: visas, uk, ukraine

I am planning to visit the UK and Ukraine at the same time, is this possible with one visa or do I need multiple visas? If I take a Ukraine tourist visa which other countries can I visit?

Comment: What is your citizenship? A UK visa doesn’t enable you to enter the Ukraine or vice versa https://mfa.gov.ua/en/consular-affairs/entering-ukraine/visa-requirements-for-foreigners. Difficult to be in both countries at the same time!

Answer (score 5):

**You cannot visit the UK and Ukraine on the same visa**. None are part of the Schengen zone, both of the visas are only for their own country. Ukraine is not in the EU and the UK won't be for much longer either.